# problem with all caps and i

Tags: calligraphy

[image: probelm]

as u can see, the text is in all caps and when i type in the letter I, i still has the dot on top of it!

for further example:
[image]

Comment: It's a bad font, choose another one or replace it in your OS with a fresh copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have "Turkish" selected. As far as I can tell (since I know virtually nothing about Turkish), this is a correct/semi-correct behavior as Turkish differentiates between a dotted and dotless i in both capitals and lower case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

If I type "in law", set all caps, and set Turkish language in the palette and then cycle the font face, all fonts on my system exhibit either the behavior in the question or have a non-printable/undefined glyph.

Comment: thank u,,,so much,,,you've saved my life

Comment: Very perceptive catch